# Disable any OTG from USB on Samsung

Tags: usb-on-the-go

is there a way I could stop any flash OTG from accessing the tablet?
    I don't want the user to read or write anything to it
I don't want to use the OTG anymore, the tablet is rooted. It's a samsung tab A 2016 with Android 6.
Thank you

Comment: What tablet is it, and what Android version are you on? Do you still need other USB-OTG devices (such as a mouse) to work? Is rooting the tablet or installing a custom ROM an acceptable solution? Please [edit] your question to add these details.

Comment: Edited sir..it's version 6 & i won't need it.. It can be rooted.. Any help is greatly appreciated..